# How to disable CSS Class on particular DIV

Tags: html, css, class, styles

I want to disable class automatically applied on div.

```
<div class="A B">
```

I want to disable Class 'A' but not 'B'. How could I do that ?

Comment: Could you be more clearly? Do you want some CSS that disables the class, or some JavaScript?

Comment: Add this as a jQuery function somewhere. 
`$('.A').removeClass('B');`

Comment: You can't stop an element form being a member of a class using CSS. There is no such thing an an inherited class.

Comment: *no javascript, jquery allowed* : jQuery is javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for CSS that says. Don't listen to class A.

Alas, there is no such CSS.

- Either you have to remove the class A from your source code.
- Or you remove the class from the DOM by means of JavaScript.
- Or you must overwrite your CSS in class B that any value that was set in class A gets initial/neutral values (sometimes it's the value 'initial', sometimes its the value 'auto' or 'none')

Comment: what about .B:not(.A)? that would listen to elements with class B that doesn't have class A.

Comment: @IMPixel Well, not as of 2014, when I wrote this answer

Comment: @IMPixel This will not help, if `.A {}` is already defined. `B:not(.A) {}` will not override `.A` automatically

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for a javascript...

Add a id to your div and use

```
<div id="whatever" class="A B"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.document.onload = function(){ 
        document.getElementById("whatever").className = "A";
    }     
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in straight js, give the div an ID:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="A B"></div>
```

And then in js:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.remove("B");
```

Comment: And to add it back: document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add("B");

Answer (score 0):

I think that I accomplished succesefully. :)

For example I have my html code :

```
<a class="m2" href="#">Some text here, with bold</a>
<a class="m2 nobold" href="#">Some text here, without bold</a>
```

I use CSS for the first text

```
.m2 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And for disable it, I use

```
.nobold {
font-weight: normal;
}
```

And it apply both, but you can change settings from the other CSS class ...

Answer (score 0):

This code will act magically....

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $( "div" ).removeClass( 'your_class_name' );
      });
</script>
```